# compatibility of ros melodic with ros kinetic

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have robot running with ROS arm Kinetic version, and i have created QT based GUI which is running from ROS Melodic version using action lib messaging.

is both version have compatibility for communication purpose ? or do I need to have same ROS version on robot and application running machine ?

is ROS melodic have backward compatibility to ROS Kinetic ?

Thanks & Regards
Yogesh Dusane

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/360007/compatibility-of-ros-melodic-with-ros-kinetic/) by [Yogesh Dusane](https://answers.ros.org/users/52089/yogesh-dusane/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2020-08-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

0% supported compatability. You **may** find that it works OK as long as nothing major changed in the libraries you're using, but no one is going to offer support for it and its not recommended. You should run the same ROS version.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-08-20**:
This seems a bit too pessimistic.

Many Q&As here on this site about the same topic essentially say: as long as the messages you intent to exchange between nodes haven't changed, things will most likely work.

And "not changed" means both syntax (so names and types of fields) as well as semantics (ie: meaning of fields). The latter will be more difficult to diagnose though.

For many messages involved in tele-operation type tasks (ie: `geometry_msgs`, `tf`, `std_msgs` and `control_msgs`) this is the case. For messages created by the OP him/herself, that would of course always under his/her control.

Is mixing ROS versions "officially supported" (whatever that means): no, it isn't. And if you post questions here about things not working with such a setup, you'll most likely be told "first try with everything running the same ROS version".

Will it work: provided you take the things mentioned earlier into account: there is a good chance.

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-08-20**:
That is all true. I frame it this way because its really not recommended and could have a bunch of potential problems. Also future readers might read an answer approving of that as instruction to do so (and potentially with a different situation what won't work), which I'd like to avoid.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-08-20**:
I agree with you.

The phrasing of your answer however made it sound like it's not possible at all.

"supported" could be understood to mean: technically not possible with the current implementation.

I realise you mean to say "there is no support" as in: when asking questions, you will not receive any support, as it's likely going to be the cause of whatever problem you are running into.

Those are two different things, and I felt the extra nuance could help here.

**Comment by [Yogesh Dusane](https://answers.ros.org/users/52089/yogesh-dusane/) on 2020-08-20**:
Thank you both of you to clarify on this, which make me to take decision move on to the same version of ROS.